# Why is 'dress the way people want' incorrect?

Tags: vocabulary

Here's the problem:

> **Choose the correct word or pick both if both are correct.**
>
> Pupils can *wear*/*dress* the way they want.

The key answer on my book tells me the answer is wear only. But why? Why dress is wrong? Isn't it the same as wear/put on?

Comment: Did you copy the question correctly?  Can you please tell us the name of the textbook? Thanks

Comment: @Mari-LouA after reading randomhead's answer I made sure if I copied it correctly then realized that I didn't. Silly of me. Sorry for that. At least now I know wear isn't appropriate there. Thanks to randomhead.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's from vocabulary in use pre-intermediate and intermediate by stuart redman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is so blatantly incorrect that I wonder if there was a printing error.

**To wear** is a transitive verb (at least in the sense of "to clothe oneself with"). It requires a direct object. To say "Pupils can wear the way they want" makes no sense; if you wanted to use that verb you would have to rewrite the sentence and say "Pupils can wear *whatever* they want."

**To dress** is an intransitive verb and does not require a direct object. "Pupils can dress the way they want" is a perfectly correct sentence.

Comment: The OP copied the question incorrectly. Always a good idea to double-check beforehand.